# Data Detectors in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, email, nstextfield, nstextview

I want to add a data detector in an NSTextField / NSTextView like in Mail (e.g. date, email, URL, etc).

Does anyone have an idea how to do this ? I think I saw it in TextEdit's source code but when I checked it was 2005's version and I can't find the new source code.

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the formatter outlet of the object. Built in formatters are [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and  [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

[image]

You can define custom formatters by extending the [NSFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. There is a chapter in [Aaron Hillegass](http://www.bignerdranch.com/instructors/hillegass.shtml) excellent '[Cocoa Programming for Max OS X](http://www.bignerdranch.com/products.shtml)' on Creating NSFormatters.

To detect dates, url, email address, etc. within the body of some text, you can use the [Latent Semantic Mapping Framework](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/TextFonts/Reference/LatentSemanticMapping/index.html). It's a public API as of Leopard but there isn't a great deal of documentation for it. There is also a command line tool called [lsm](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lsm.1.html) that would allow you to test any custom extractors you want to use. It is a C API and not integrated into Cocoa as far as I know so you'd need to wire it up yourself

Comment: thanks for the answer. But how do I use NSFormatter to detect data in text ? for example if I have a text that goes 'Hey how are you ? Let's meet sunday. My number is 123-555-000'. If I received this in Mail and mouse-overed 'sunday' it would propose me to ad the event to iCal, and if I mouse-overed '123-555-000' it would propose me to add it to a contact or something. How do I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: @Alexandre Cassagne: Ah - OK. Have added a paragraph on the Latent Semantic Mapping framework which I think is what you want.

Comment: It's gonna be tough to work with, but it's what I'm looking for.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Snow Leopard you can now enable Data Detectors in a NSTextView by simply clicking the appropriate checkbox in the IB inspector.

Comment: Thanks – much simpler than the above XD