# Make an URL in an NSTextFieldCell clickable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

There are two parts to this question:

(1) How can I detect URLs in a given text?

(2) How can I make clickable a part of the text in a text field cell (in a table view)? I would like URLs, when clicked upon, to open in the default web browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For making URLs clickable please take a look at this guide from Apple:
[Embedding Hyperlinks in NSTextField and NSTextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1487/_index.html)

For the first part, are you married to using an NSTextField? The reason is that NSTextView provides this automatically (it is just a checkbox in IB). Otherwise, have a look at [this answer on StackOverflow regarding the Latent Semantic Mapping Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034889/data-detectors-in-cocoa).

I have not used it so I am afraid that I cannot offer any suggestions on it.

Comment: The code from the Apple guide doesn't work on NSTextField for me...